# expect - ssh - two possible passwords - or how to jump of expect block and still use send clausule

Tags: ssh, expect, if-statement

first I need to say that I am avare of using public and private keys but this did not solve my problem. Also I am aware that I can use two scripts (one with password1 and second with password2) and run them two times but I am wondering why following did not works. I am trying to make expect script that will connect through ssh and check if one of two passwords are correct. For this I am checking exit codes of script:

- 0 - password1 was correct
- 1 - password2 was correct
- 2,3,4,5,6 - some other exit codes, insipred by this post: [expect send weird
  constructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13705020/linux-expect-send-weird-constructions)

There can be more possible login prompt on remote machine and I would like to make this script as generic as possible, so I cannot rely on the login prompt string. So far I have this code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/expect
set username "username";
set remote_server "machine";
set password1 "badpassword";
set password2 "goodpassword";

set timeout 5;
set pretype 0;
set retcode 0;


if { $pretype == 0 } {
  spawn ssh -q ${username}@${remote_server}
  expect {
    "no)?"    { send "yes\r"; }
    "denied" {
                puts "Can't login to $remote_server. Check username and password\n";
                set retcode 2;
             }
    "telnet:" {
                puts "Can't connect to $remote_server via SSH or Telnet. Something went definitely wrong\n";
                set retcode 3;
              }
    "failed" {
                puts "Host $remote_server exists. Check ssh_hosts file\n";
                set retcode 4;
             }
    timeout {
                puts "Timeout problem. Host $remote_server doesn't respond\n";
                set retcode 5;
            }
    "refused" {
                puts "Host $remote_server refused to SSH. That is insecure.\n";
                set retcode 6;
                }
    "assword:" {    set pretype 1; send "${password1}\r";  }
  }
} else {
    expect{
        "assword:" {    send "${password2}\r"; exit 1; }
        timeout { exit 0; }
    }
}
```

The idea behind this is following: if I type wrong password I will have second opportunity to type correct one. So If I type wrong password first time my script should continue in else branch (because I `set pretype to 1`). Here I will expecting prompt for entering password again. So I will send second password and exit with code 1 (password2 was OK). If the timeout in else branch expires (the "password:" string did not match), most probably I already have login prompt, so script will exit with code 0 (password1 was OK). But this did not working, and if I ran this inside debugger the last line I saw was:

```
send: sending "badpassword\r\r" to { exp4 }
```

I do not know why this happens, but seems that script never reaches the else branch. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`set pretype 1` in the `if` block cannot make it go to the `else` block again. No programming languages would do this. You need something like a *loop* (using `while` or `exp_continue`) here.

Following is an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set passwords { bad1 bad2 bad3 good }

spawn ssh -o PreferredAuthentications=keyboard-interactive \
          -o NumberOfPasswordPrompts=[llength $passwords] root@tree

set try 0
expect {
    "Password: " {
        if { $try >= [llength $passwords] } {
            send_error ">>> wrong passwords\n"
            exit 1
        }

        send [lindex $passwords $try]\r
        incr try
        exp_continue
    }

    "bash-4.2" {
        interact
    }

    timeout {
        send_error ">>> timed out\n"
        exit 1
    }
}
```